# Find out if row /item in DataGrid is in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, radio-button, edit, mode

In asp.net 3.5 I have a DataGrid. It has several rows of data. I have radio buttons out of the datagrid. The data grid has a column for drop down list in EDIT mode. So I click one of the radio buttons and it does a postback. I want to know in this check changed event for radio button if any of the rows in DataGrid are in edit mode. How do I do that?
I can loop through the DataGrid like this

```
For Each item As DataGridItem In dgEditTime.Items
        Trace.Warn("The item index is:" & item.ItemIndex)

    Next
```

But how to find out if what row is in edit mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a `GridView` you can get the [EditIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex.aspx) by calling:

```
int editIndex = yourGridView.EditIndex
```

If you are using the [old DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.edititemindex%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) control, you can call EditItemIndex:

```
int editIndex = yourDG.EditItemIndex
```

If your code doesn't work as you expect, is likely that you are probably rebinding the data on every postback and hence, the `EditItemIndex` (or `EditIndex` depending on the actual control you are using) is therefore reset to the original state.

Comment: I am using the old DataGrid. So EditItemIndex helped me. Thanks.

Comment: @RookieAppler if you can, change it to a `GridView` since is a better component. Offers more functionality out of the box.